# how to send value to pub/sub when Cloud Build all step finished

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-build

I want to send target property value to pub/sub after all step of cloud build finish

```
var target = "test"

op, err := cloudbuildService.Projects.Builds.Create(os.Getenv("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT"), &cloudbuild.Build{
        Steps: []*cloudbuild.BuildStep{
            {...},
            {...}
        },
        Artifacts: &cloudbuild.Artifacts{
            Objects: &cloudbuild.ArtifactObjects{
                Location: dst,
                Paths:    []string{...},
            },
        },
    }).Do()
```

please tell me how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "target property"? What do you want to send to PubSub?

Comment: thank you commnet. targt prperty is here. `var target = "test"`

Comment: Hmmm, I think I understand. You want to add your own property to the automatic pubsub message generated at the end of the build, correct? If so, where to add it? In attribute? in the body? If not, I didn't understand!!

Comment: thank yo replay. I want to add it to attribute!

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize the PubSub message envelop send at the end of the Cloud Build builds. The content of the PubSub message is the as Build resource in the `message.data` described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/subscribe-build-notifications)

Because you will receive the Build resource description, a workaround is to add a dummy substitution variable name "_TARGET" and with the value that you want.

In a subsequent process, you will be able to get this value and act accordingly. However, because it's not a PubSub attribute, you won't be able to leverage the pubsub filter feature.

Comment: thank you advice. ok... I know logic. but how I write this using golang?